# Is there a bug in Python's multiprocess pool leaving defunct processes in spawn mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

We've noticed a bunch of defunct (zombie) processes being leftover in one of our deployments and managed to produce a very minimal program showing the issue:

**multi.py**:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, set_start_method

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    set_start_method('spawn')
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
        p.close()
        p.join()
```

This program seems to be leaving zombie processes but it was hard to catch since running this from a regular shell will cause the shell to reap the zombies.

In our deployment we have this run from another python program, so to simulate it we have this:

**main.py**:

```py
from subprocess import run
from time import sleep

while True:
    result = run(["python", "multi.py"], capture_output=True)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
    result = run(["ps", "-ef", "--forest"], capture_output=True)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'), flush=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Running **main.py** produces this output:

```
[1, 4, 9]

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0 11 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 python main.py
root         8     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        17     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef --forest

[1, 4, 9]

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  6 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 python main.py
root         8     1  3 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        19     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        28     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef --forest

[1, 4, 9]

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  4 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 python main.py
root         8     1  1 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        19     1  3 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        30     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        39     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef --forest

[1, 4, 9]

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  3 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 python main.py
root         8     1  1 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        19     1  1 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        30     1  4 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        41     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 [python] <defunct>
root        50     1  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef --forest
```

On the other hand, the following program **does not** produce defunct processes:

**main-sig.py**:

```py
from os import wait
import signal
from subprocess import run
from time import sleep

def chld_handler(_signum, _frame):
    wait()

signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, chld_handler)

while True:
    result = run(["python", "multi.py"], capture_output=True)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'))
    result = run(["ps", "-ef", "--forest"], capture_output=True)
    print(result.stdout.decode('utf-8'), flush=True)
    sleep(1)
```

Also the following simple shell script **deoes not** produce zombies:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while :; do
    python multi.py
    ps -ef --forest
    sleep 1
done
```

Is this a bug in Python or you are expected to handle any zombies coming from a child processes (like Bash is seemingly doing)?

All code and a `Dockerfile` to easily reproduce the issue are available here:
https://github.com/viktorvia/python-multi-issue

The issue is reproducible with Python 3.9.6, 3.7.4 and 3.7.11.

Comment: I think this is a leaking `resource_tracker` process, since the only place in the python source (that I saw) where it is reaped with `waitpid()` is in a private method `_stop()` called only from some tests. I've opened [bug 44724](https://bugs.python.org/issue44724).

Comment: I've reached to the same conclusion. If you put `print(subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-ef", "--forest"]).decode())` inside the pool context manger, you'll notice that each new zombie PID is the process that was running `/usr/local/bin/python -c from multiprocessing.resource_tracker import main;main(5)`.

Comment: You can search bugs.python.org to see if you can find a corresponding issue.

Comment: Apparently if your "regular shell" is inside `screen`, it *doesn't* reap the zombies; at least, not by my experience.

Comment: The addition of the signal handler in the parent script solved it for me, too.  Kudos to @Viktor!